# How do I set the type, for custom store, when I pass store via setContext or component prop?

Tags: typescript, svelte, jsdoc, sveltekit, svelte-store

When using SvelteKit, the `store` must always be created in the route `page`/`layout`, otherwise there will be problems with the status being up-to-date after refreshing.
You can't create a `store` in an imported module, because the server-side module only loads once, and this causes errors in the `store`.
All this leads to a certain situation with types.

**The problem:**

I create and pass the store from `+page.svelte` to `Child.svelte`, via `setContext`:

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script>
  import Child from "./Child.svelte";
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
  import { setContext } from "svelte";
  
  function createCount() {
    /** @type {import("svelte/store").Writable<number>} */
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(0);
    
    return {
      subscribe,
      increment: () => update(n => n + 1),
      decrement: () => update(n => n - 1),
      reset: () => set(0)
    };
  }
  
  export const count = createCount();
  
  setContext("store", count);
</script>

<Child/>
```

```html
<!-- Child.svelte -->
<script>
import { getContext } from "svelte";
  
  const count = getContext("store");
</script>

<h1>The count is {$count}</h1>

<button on:click={count.increment}>+</button>
<button on:click={count.decrement}>-</button>
<button on:click={count.reset}>reset</button>
```

In `Child.svelte` the type for `store` count is `any`:
[image: obraz]

And it should be as in the place of the declaration:
[image: obraz]

**That's what it should be** the type of `store`, returned from getContext("store"):

```
const count: {
    subscribe: (this: void, run: Subscriber<number>, invalidate?: Invalidator<number> | undefined) => Unsubscriber;
    increment: () => void;
    decrement: () => void;
    reset: () => void;
}
```

Passing via `<Child {count}/>` has the same problem.
[image: obraz]

**QUESTION:** How can this be done?

#### Alternative

It doesn't. You can only create a `store` in a module, and import it - then the types are preserved.
But this creates some problems with `store` validity, as I wrote about at the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two primary options: Use `preprocess-svelte` and write TypeScript or add JSDoc type annotations.

With TS:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';

    // Prop
    export let count: StoreType;

    // Context
    const store = getContext<StoreType>('context');
</script>
```

With JSDoc:

```html
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';

    // Prop
    /** @type {StoreType} */
    export let count;

    // Context
    /** @type {StoreType} */
    const store = getContext('context');
</script>
```

You can declare types in separate `.d.ts` files or use [`@typedef`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html).

---

The `createCount` function can be extracted to a separate file without issue. That way its return type can also be used when typing props/contexts. E.g.

```js
// create-count.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export function createCount() {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(0);

    return {
        subscribe,
        increment: () => update(n => n + 1),
        decrement: () => update(n => n - 1),
        reset: () => set(0),
    };
}
```

```html
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';

    /** @type {ReturnType<import('./create-count').createCount>} */
    export let count;

    /** @type {ReturnType<import('./create-count').createCount>} */
    const store = getContext('context');
</script>
```

In TS this is cleaner, since you can just import the type as part of regular code and use type aliases.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import type { createCount } from './create-count';
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';

    export let count: Count;

    const store = getContext<Count>('context');

    type Count = ReturnType<typeof createCount>;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this completely solves the problem.

Comment: The second suggestion was great. I exported the type from the same file (in your example it would be `export type Count = ReturnType<typeof createCount>` in `./create-count` since it felt cleaner to only import the type wherever needed instead of importing the creator-function many everywhere